# TypeScript OO Design - using a subclass when only the constructor is different

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am using some ES6 classes with TypeScript to construct a user interface.  I have a base class called `Control`.  I want a way to construct a Button, which is an instance of `Control` with some properties already set.  I have implemented `Button` as a subclass of `Control`.

However I noticed that the only thing that happens in my subclass is that it calls super(), with the control `type` set to 'button'.  Button also makes certain control properties become mandatory.  It feels wrong. Should I really be using a subclass?  What would be the good OOP way for doing this?

```
interface ControlOptions {
  type: string;
  label?: string;
  onClick?: () => void;   // optional here
  submit?: boolean;
  transition?: Transition
}

class Control {
  constructor(options: ControlOptions) {

  }

  // Some methods left out for brevity.
}


interface ButtonOptions {
  label: string
  onClick: () => any    // mandatory here
  submit?: boolean
  transition?: Transition
}

// should this be a subclass?
class Button extends Control {
  constructor(options: ButtonOptions) {
    let controlProps = { type: 'button', ...options };

    super(controlProps);

    if (options.transition) {
      options.transition.setSource(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, the *only* change between the two classes is `type: 'button'`?

Comment: Almost- the onClick option for Button is mandatory, but for Control it is optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems ok to me. Just because the subclass only has a small amount of changes doesn't mean it's not necessary or wrong. I quite often create classes that are very small or hardly do anything.

Also, having a subclass enforce certain data being passed to it be mandatory is perfectly fine in this case because the base class allows for it—the base class expects a value or undefined, so it's ok to just pass it a value from the sub class. On the other hand, having the base class expect a value and making it optional in the sub class would indeed be wrong and a compile error.

I'd recommend these changes for brevity though:

```
interface ControlOptions {
  label?: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
  submit?: boolean;
  transition?: Transition;
}

class Control {
  constructor(type: string, options: ControlOptions = {}) {
  }
}

interface ButtonOptions extends ControlOptions {
  onClick: () => void; // make mandatory
}

class Button extends Control {
  constructor(options: ButtonOptions) {
    super('button', options);

    if (options.transition) {
      options.transition.setSource(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
class Control {
  constructor(options: { type: string; } & ControlOptions) {
  }
}

class Button extends Control {
  constructor(options: ButtonOptions) {
    super({ type: 'button', ...options });
    // etc...
  }
}
```